# Establish audio channel between browsers using WebRTC

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, webrtc

I want to develop application that allows to establish audio channel between two browsers using WebRTC technology. Can you provide step by step tutorial that allows to run sample application?

Comment: Have you tried anything? What research have you done yourself? Maybe [this tutorial on webrtc-experiment.com](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/WebRTC-PeerConnection.html) will help.

Answer (score 0):

As @Benjamin Trent said, check out [webrtc-experiments.com](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/WebRTC-PeerConnection.html) and also the source for apptrc.appspot.com [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/webrtc/blob/master/samples/web/content/apprtc/)